# Persisting id across components via params in Vue

Tags: vue.js, parameters, vue-router

I have a route path that looks like this `/courses/:id/modules/:id`, I am passing the `:id` of the course and modules via params like this

```
<router-link
    :to="{
        name: 'course-modules',
        params: { id: item.id, onlineClassId: item.online_class_id }
    }"
    class="forum__link">
    {{ item.title }}
</router-link>
```

I need to use the IDs to make a `GET` request.

But when I refresh the page, the component loses hold of `onlineClassId` which throws an error. Is there a way I persist that ID?

Thanks.

Comment: are these ids being used on the route?

Comment: @HamiltonGabriel yes they are. When I log `this.$route.params` to the console, the first time the link is clicked it contains `id` and `onlineClassId`, but on refresh, it contains only `id`.

Comment: Can you send a photo before and after?

Comment: @HamiltonGabriel photo of what please?
Here is the params before refresh `{id: 1, onlineClassId: 1}`, after refresh it becomes `{id: "1"}`

Comment: as you do to get the onlineClassId, something is probably mutating the value. It makes no sense if you're passing two id's, one staying and the other not.

Comment: You tried ? :to="{name: 'course-modules', query: { id: item.id, onlineClassId: item.online_class_id}}

Comment: Query works fine, I figured the issue, in `router.js` I was using `/courses/:id/modules/:id` instead of `courses/:onlineClassId/modules/:id`.
Thank you @HamiltonGabriel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the issue, in `router.js` I was using `/courses/:id/modules/:id` instead of `courses/:onlineClassId/modules/:id`